# Can Scribus print a document in a quarter fold?

Tags: scribus

I would like to print my A4-sized document in a quarter fold (also called a French fold or right angle fold). Can Scribus do this as four A6 pages like Microsoft Publisher?

I've found this similar question [Page layout with Scribus](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57798/page-layout-with-scribus) but it seems to indicate that Scribus can't directly do this.

Currently I create a blank A4 page, set the units to centimetres and insert a vertical line at 10.5 cm from the left edge and a horizontal line at 14.85 cm from the top. Before printing I delete the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The short answer

**YES**, you can.

## The longer version

There are two possible scenarios:

1. *If you are having your document printed by a **professional print shop***, you could design four A6 pages and hand over the final pdf file to the printer.
2. *If you are **home-printing** your document*, the way you are doing it probably is the right direction - you may want to use guides (`Page` > `Manage Guides`) instead of inserting lines and deleting them afterwards.

This [**greeting card template**](https://www.scribus-templates.net/2018/05/mam.html) could help getting a better idea.

## The clarification

Scribus and Publisher are distinct computer softwares with distinct philosophies. Publisher is aimed at home and small-business markets, or projects that do not require a high-level of versatility. Scribus is a top-notch professional desktop publishing software, with advanced features and functionalities. Starting with small projects is a great way to learn about its capabilities - and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Scribus should not be used for printing.

Depending on your setup, Scribus can reliably print every document or it will need (a lot of) tweaking for some not so uncommon documents to be printed.

Scribus is a tool for generating PDFs that, then will be printed.
So the general rule is: create a PDF from Scribus and use a PDF reader to print it.

There are tools like [pdfsam](https://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/) that can then "impose" your PDF(s).

If you're creating a very simple document, you might be able to create a new Scribus document, of the size of the paper, and paste each page of the original document. Sometimes it works better this way, sometimes you'd better first create a pdf.